# How to force LXDE for XRDP connections on 18.04

Tags: remote-desktop, lxde, xrdp

I'm trying to small terminal server going and I'm struggling heavily with the performance and desktop setup.

When I create new profiles and they connect to the terminal server, instead of getting a LXDE Desktop, they get the ... beaver desktop (It's probably Gnome I think?) and it's ridiculously slow, maybe reaching 5 frames per second with only a single user.

I've installed LXDE but when I use my windows clients to connect to the Ubuntu with RDP, it creates a session with that slow beaver instead of the black LXDE desktop.

Is there a way to force users to only use LXDE?

Answer (score 4):

Well, nevermind. After hours of no results I now randomly stumbled upon the solution.

```
update-alternatives --config x-session-manager
```

and then select the LXDE option...